# Swift Selective Orientation Issues moving from Portrait to Landscape

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, landscape, portrait

Environment:

- Using the latest Xcode 8.3
- Language: Swift3
- Devices are all updated (iPhone 7 v10.3.1)
- (Target -> Deployment Info -> Device Orientation) is set to Portrait for all options for 'Devices'

Scenario:

- I have 2 ViewControllers (VC1 and VC2), both which inherit from UIViewController.
- VC1 is always meant to be portrait
- VC2 is always meant to be landscape
- VC1 and VC2 have all their subviews and objects configured and added to the ViewController's view in the viewDidLoad call.
- I am presenting VC2 from VC1 via the call (as I need a nav bar):

  ```
  let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2())
  self.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
  ```
- Whether VC2 inherits from a UINavigationController or UIViewController has made no difference to the occurrence to the issue.
- AppDelegate.swift enforces the orientation as such:

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
      if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {
          if rootViewController is VC2 {
          let vc2 = rootViewController as! VC2
          if vc2.isPresented {
              return .landscapeRight
          }
      }
      return .portrait
  }
  ```
- The above function uses this function to find the topViewControllerWithRootViewController:

  ```
  private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
      if (rootViewController == nil) {
          return nil
      }
      if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self)) {
          return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
      } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)) {
          return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
      } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
          return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
      }
      return rootViewController
  }
  ```

Issue:

- This usually always works however in some instances the view will result in VC2 being presented vertically with properties being derived from a horizontal view:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjfBW.png)

- This happens randomly with no errors being shown in Xcode (including it's debug console).

Additional Notes:

- Please note there are tasks being run on background threads that require the use of the GPU. These are declared from ViewControllers other than VC1 and VC2.
- Perhaps this might cause time sensitive device orientation functions to be called in the incorrect order.
- I have tried the implementations from the following links:

http://www.jairobjunior.com/blog/2016/03/05/how-to-rotate-only-one-view-controller-to-landscape-in-ios-slash-swift/